# Can we make [nextjs13] a synonym of [next.js13]?

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, tags, synonym-request

[nextjs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/nextjs) is already a synonym of [next.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/next.js), and the [nextjs13](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/nextjs13) and [next.js13](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/next.js13) were created on August 20th and November 1st respectively.

- [next.js13](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/next.js13) has 336 questions, and no tag wiki.
- [nextjs13](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/nextjs13) has 1265 questions, and no tag wiki either.

Even though the latter has more questions than the former, I suggest making [nextjs13](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/nextjs13) a synonym of [next.js13](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/next.js13) to keep the consistency between the two.

Comment: I agree. Both of them are essentially the same.